# Locating a user using geolocation?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I would like to know what the best way is to get the latitude and longitude of the user visiting my page. And i want it to work in IE as well, so html5 is out of the question :)

Thanks

Comment: Is using a server-side language an option?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript to make a call out to this service - which will return all the major details you are looking for:

```
http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js
```

It will make JavaScript functions available to you with the following info:

```
function geoip_country_code() { return 'CA'; }
function geoip_country_name() { return 'Canada'; }
function geoip_city()         { return 'Toronto'; }
function geoip_region()       { return 'ON'; }
function geoip_region_name()  { return 'Ontario'; }
function geoip_latitude()     { return '44.7150'; }
function geoip_longitude()    { return '-76.3470'; }
function geoip_postal_code()  { return ''; }
function geoip_area_code()    { return ''; }
function geoip_metro_code()   { return ''; }
```

Note the data above is just a faked example...

Answer (score 0):

Google has a great geocoding API ... http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ ... which unlike most Geo IP based lookups, uses a number of different methods, including sensors (i.e. iPhone GPS) if available, or gears, down to simple Geo IP lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If a relatively coarse location is sufficient (usually at the city level), then a Geo IP database might be appropriate (there are several providers for those, just google it).

Note also, that those can be fooled relatively easy by proxy servers. But in *most* cases it should be fine.